# How to take the input from a javascript generated form and push it into an array

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to develop a webpage that takes a number of inputs, the number of which is decided upon by the user.

I have created a field that is on the page for the user to input data, as well as a button that when clicked adds a new field for the user to input additional data. Every time this button is clicked a new field appears.

When I click on my test button which adds the user data to an empty array, I get a "TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of null
    at storeValue" message.

```
userTimes = [];

// function that adds another time field
let addButton = function () {

var form = document.createElement('form');
form.setAttribute('method', 'post');
form.setAttribute('action', '#');
//form.style?

let mile2Form = document.createElement('input');

mile2Form.setAttribute('type', 'time');
//mile2Form.style.top = '200px';

form.appendChild(mile2Form);
document.body.appendChild(form);

//document.getElementById('form').style.bottom = '-100px';


}
//function that adds times into userTimes array
let storeValue = function () {

    let inputTime = document.getElementById('mile1').value;
    let inputTime2 = document.getElementById('input').value;

    userTimes.push(inputTime, inputTime2);


}
```

I expect that the inputs from the existing field, as well as any additional fields added by the user be pushed into the userTimes array.

Comment: It means that either `document.getElementById('mile1')` or `document.getElementById('input')` can't find anything. They return null. Then you're trying to essentially do `null.value` which is not going to work. Are you sure the elements with these IDs exist?

Comment: Your HTML has no elements with ID's `mile1` or `input`, hence your two `getElementById` invocations return `null`, and trying to access `null.value` throws the error you're seeing.